# Highcharts: How to reduce label width / height

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to reduce the width of the bar. I achieved the same by using pointWidth attribute. However, the padding before and after the label "1 page" is too high. I want to compress the whole graph similar to the second image.

Does anyone know?

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting the height of the chart :

chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            height: 250, // this can be calculated on the basis of categories length along      with some default margin at the bottom and top of the chart
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can set use pointPadding / groupPadding http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.groupPadding
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.pointPadding

Comment: Hello Sebastian, thank you. I tried the above but it did not work. This is what I did f.series(:data=> page_depth, borderWidth: 0, pointWidth: 10, groupPadding: 0, pointPadding: 0).

Comment: Add the padding options to the plot options, not the series.
You will also need to change the height of your container element if you want the chart to be smaller.
You can eliminate the pointWidth altogether using this approach.